# C++ set of struct fails to find/erase by element

Tags: c++, set

As shown below, the set of y-axis intervals (i.e., vertical) needs to satisfy two requirements:

1) it sorts all intervals from bottom to up;

2) it returns insertion failure if the new interval is overlapping with any interval in set. This is similar to STL `set<int>` returns `pair.second == false` when inserting a duplicate int.

My guess is that the customized comparison function `cmp_set` is causing the bug of find/erase failure, also the order of intervals is descending(shall be ascending?). Since STL set relies on binary search on finding the interval, thus it fails.

How shall this be fixed? The problem is that the comparison function `cmp_set` shall handle the above two requirements 1) and 2), but return int value as -1/1/0 seems not working. Changing it to bool comparison function only returns true/false which cannot detect overlapping intervals.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

struct Interval {
    int down;
    int up; 

    Interval(int d, int u) {
        down = d;                        
        up = u;
    }   

    bool operator==(const Interval& other) {
        return down == other.down && up == other.up;
    }   
};

auto cmp_set = [](const Interval& a, const Interval& b) {
    // if (a.up <= b.down) {//a's up is below b's down
    //     return -1;  //sort a before b, like a < b 
    // } else if (a.down >= b.up) {//a's down is above b's up
    //     return 1; //sort a after b, like a > b 
    // } else {
    //     return 0; //overlap. Very similar to the Interval Overlap
    // }
    if (max(a.down, b.down) < min(a.up, b.up)) return 0; //overlap of intervals
    else { //sort the two intervals 
        if(a.up <= b.down) return -1; 
        else return 1;
    }   
};        

void print(set<Interval, decltype(cmp_set)>& s) {
    for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); it++) {
        cout << it->down << "->" << it->up << ", ";
    }                                
    cout << endl;
}


int main()
{
    set<Interval, decltype(cmp_set)> s(cmp_set);


    s.insert(Interval{1, 3});
    s.insert(Interval{3, 4});
    print(s); //3->4, 1->3, 

    auto iter = s.find(Interval{3, 4});
    if (iter == s.end()) cout << "not find" << endl; //not find

    s.erase(Interval{3, 4});  //fail to remove the Interval
    print(s); //still contains 3->4, 1->3, 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your comparison is not correct.  It needs to be a `strict-weak-order`-ing.  Also, your comparison should be returning `true` or `false`, not 0, -1 or 1.  Maybe you are getting confusing C++ with another computer language?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzieThank you so much for your quick reply! yes, it works in Java. Could you please help me to fix this bug?

Comment: Well that explains it -- do **not** use other computer languages as a model when writing C++ code.  The bottom line is this -- you need to return `true` if `a` comes before `b` in terms of order, `false` otherwise.  The 0, 1, -1 stuff, leave it alone -- it doesn't fit in this scenario.

Comment: Got it. However, what shall be done to satisfy both requirements 1) and 2) in one comparison function of C++ set? It seems not possible, then how shall the insertion be handled if customized comparison function can only handle sorting but not overlapping detection.

Comment: Then you are using a data structure that doesn't fit your needs.  The strict-weak-ordering is how `std::set` determines where items are placed.  Either you have to somehow write your code to fit that paradigm, or use a different data structure.  Also note that `std::set` doesn't use `==` at all in any scenario, so writing an `operator ==` resulted in a "no-op".

Comment: I see. what does "no-op" mean?

Comment: "No-op" meaning "no operation was done".  What I'm saying is that `std::set` doesn't use equality operators at all in its implementation.  Equality is done strictly by using `<`.

Comment: Interval sets are a bit tricky. I once found [Boost.Icl](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/icl/doc/html/index.html). A simple approach is to store intervals in a `std::vector`. Every value with even index remarks a start of an interval, every uneven an end. To retrieve whether a value is inside an interval (and which) a binary search (e.g. `std::lower_bound`) can be done. Insertion and removal must keep the contents sorted and have to be done carefully (or denied), concerning overlapping.

Comment: ...  Due to storage in `std::vector`, insertion and removal are a bit expansive but find (done like described above) is as fast as in a `std::set`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your comparison correctly, for the set you need:

```
auto cmp_set = [](const Interval& a, const Interval& b) { 
    return a.down >= b.up; 
}
```

Meaning that if a comes before b in the set, a will start after b will end.

Overlapping for set occurs when !(a < b || b < a). 
Note that for this to be strict order you have to ensure that (down < up) for every interval.